# Update em três tabelas

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

Bom dia, gostaria de saber se é possível fazer update em três tabelas ao mesmo tempo? tenho as tabelas livrosA,livrosB,livrosC que são relacionadas pela coluna id_livro, e gostaria de mudar o valor da coluna preco_livro nas três tabelas ao mesmo tempo para 99.99 sem ter que fazer update separadamente em cada tabela, se possivel também gostaria de usar a mesma lógica com o comando Delete.

Comment: em _sql-server_ acredito ser impossível. Mas por que você tem três tabelas (`livrosA`,`livrosB`,`livrosC`)? Não seria melhor, por exemplo, ter uma tabela `livros` e outra `Categoria`?? Talvez seja interessante rever sua estrutura!!

Comment: é que estou fazendo um treinamento na empresa onde trabalho e criei estas tabelas apenas para estudo pois o meu chefe pediu para pesquisar como fazer este procedimento se possível.

Comment: @wilder A alteração de preços será livro a livro ou será utilizado algum critério para alterar um conjunto de livros de uma única vez?

Answer (score 4):

Para cada tabela deve-se utilizar um comando de atualização: UPDATE. É simples de se montar. Sugiro que encapsule os 3 comandos com o par `BEGIN TRANSACTION` / `COMMIT`

```
-- código #1
declare @id_livro ____, @preco_livro ____;
set @id_livro= ___;
set @preco_livro= 99.99;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE livrosA
  set preco_livro= @preco_livro
  where id_livro = @id_livro;

UPDATE livrosB
  set preco_livro= @preco_livro
  where id_livro = @id_livro;

UPDATE livrosC
  set preco_livro= @preco_livro
  where id_livro = @id_livro;

COMMIT;
```

Declare as variáveis `@id_livro` e `@preco_livro` com o mesmo tipo de dados das colunas `id_livro` e `preco_livro`, respectivamente.

---

Há como fazer com que, por exemplo, ao alterar o preço de um livro na tabela `livrosA` o mesmo livro tenha seu preço alterado nas tabelas `livrosB` e `livrosC`. Seria através do emprego de procedimento de gatilho (*trigger*). Entretanto, para quem está iniciando no SQL Server sugiro que não use gatilhos.

Answer (score 3):

Você tem duas opções para fazer isso (além do que já é dado por **[`@José Diz`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/57789/jos%C3%A9-diz)**):

- **[`OUTPUT clause`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**.
- **[`TRIGGERS`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**.

---

Aqui está um exemplo com `OUTPUT clause`

```
CREATE TABLE BooksA(
  BookID INT,
  BookPrice MONEY
);

CREATE TABLE BooksB(
  BookID INT,
  BookPrice MONEY
);

CREATE TABLE BooksC(
  BookID INT,
  BookPrice MONEY
);

INSERT INTO BooksA VALUES
(1, 100),
(2, 200),
(3, 100);

INSERT INTO BooksB SELECT * FROM BooksA;
INSERT INTO BooksC SELECT * FROM BooksB;

DECLARE @Price MONEY = 500;
DECLARE @IDs TABLE(ID INT);

BEGIN TRAN
  UPDATE BooksA
  SET BookPrice = @Price
  OUTPUT INSERTED.BookID
  INTO @IDs
  WHERE BookPrice = 100;

  UPDATE BooksB
  SET BookPrice = @Price
  FROM BooksB BB INNER JOIN @IDs I 
  ON BB.BookID = I.ID;

  UPDATE BooksC
  SET BookPrice = @Price
  FROM BooksC BC INNER JOIN @IDs I
  ON BC.BookID = I.ID;
COMMIT TRAN

SELECT * FROM BooksA;
SELECT * FROM BooksB;
SELECT * FROM BooksC;
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2282be454ea55b474f47940f235755cc)**

---

Aqui está um exemplo com `TRIGGERS`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trig1
ON BooksA
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
IF UPDATE(BookPrice)
  BEGIN
    UPDATE BooksB
    SET BookPrice = I.BookPrice
    FROM BooksB INNER JOIN INSERTED I
    ON BooksB.BookID = I.BookID;
    --
    UPDATE BooksC
    SET BookPrice = I.BookPrice
    FROM BooksC INNER JOIN INSERTED I
    ON BooksC.BookID = I.BookID;
  END
END

UPDATE BooksA
SET BookPrice = 500
WHERE BookPrice = 100;

SELECT * FROM BooksA;
SELECT * FROM BooksB;
SELECT * FROM BooksC;
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=597c272dde06c813eee2cd44e42c85af)**

Comment: A output clause seria essa parte `OUTPUT INSERTED.BookID  INTO @IDs`, confere? Tem algum link para documentação disso? Isso é total novidade para mim, queria estudar mais, e de preferência direcionado

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado **[`OUTPUT Clause`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** ;)

Comment: @Sami O uso de procedimento de gatilho (*trigger*) é o que mais se aproxima do que o wilder solicitou, pois ele teria que alterar em uma única tabela com a alteração se refletindo nas demais tabelas. Mas a forma como a Microsoft implementou os procedimentos de gatilho gera diversas armadilhas para novatos em T-SQL. 
A implementação *for each row* (MySQL, Oracle Database) é bem mais natural de se compreender.